# vis.gam spatial interaction output as a raster grid instead of plot object

Tags: gis, spatial, gam

I am trying to create an object that can be put into tmap or another GIS platform from my model output. I created a model using the gamm4 package that has a spatial interaction term. See an example below.

```
library(geoR)
data(gambia)

fit<- gamm4(age~ s(X,Y) +s(green))

vis.gam(fit13$gam, view = c('X','Y'), plot.type = 'contour', too.far = 0.10)
```

This should produce a plot like this.
[image]

I want to convert this plot to a raster object, so that I can use it for a tmap or leaflet map, but I don't really know where to begin. Do I generate an empty raster of my study area and then populate it with the gamm output somehow?